# Can't install 'node-sass' on Ubuntu 20

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, sass, ubuntu-20.04

I use webpack 4, sass, pug and bemto. Module on windows  worked normal, but on Ubuntu:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried enter command:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

>

```
(node:8310) [DEP0139] DeprecationWarning: Calling process.umask() with no arguments is prone to race conditions and is a potential security vulnerability.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/usr/local/bin/node-sass -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/2725/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> node-sass@4.14.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /root/.npm/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
Testing binary
/snap/node/2725/bin/node: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v816FunctionTemplate3NewEPNS_7IsolateEPFvRKNS_20FunctionCallbackInfoINS_5ValueEEEENS_5LocalIS4_EENSA_INS_9SignatureEEEiNS_19ConstructorBehaviorENS_14SideEffectTypeEPKNS_9CFunctionE
npm WARN You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

UPD:

I tried:
`npm uninstall node-sass`
After:
`npm install node-sass`
Did not help.

I tried:
`npm install node-gyp` global, save, savedev

```
ERROR in ./src/sсss/critical.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-2!./src/sсss/critical.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at loadLoader (/home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (/home/gorevanova/Documents/WebStorm/webpack-static/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:47:3)
```

But problem don't leave me.

Comment: Please change the title to your question

Comment: @satanTime No problem. Which title would look better?

Comment: That describes your problem. Currently it sounds like advice.

Comment: @satanTime Title corrected. Thanks!

Comment: Node sass uses native code. It should be built using node-gyp. Try reinstalling it

Comment: @orkhan-alikhanov Did not help.  Updated the body of the question. Added a log.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run this commands:
`rm -rf ./node_modules ./package-lock.json`, then
`npm cache verify`.
*PS:* I recommend to install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

```sh
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

Also I don’t know if you already have it, but make sure to also have `build-essential` install

```sh
$ sudo apt update && apt install build-essential
```

It is a set of c++ compilers and Bunch of useful

something else that I have seen is the lack of python 2.x.x

```sh
$ sudo apt install python
```

Comment: you did everything except one thing
```npm WARN You are using a pre-release version of node and things may not work as expected
```
Also this
```
pm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /snap/bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/2725/bin/node itself.
```
it is telling you that the node version use to compile the snap for node-sass is not compatible with the current version.

That's why I mentioned nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Installing Python fixed the error for me on Ubuntu 20.14

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it worked for me

```
npm i --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check your node version before install it, node-sass has striction about node versions, shown as below:

[image]

refer to https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Answer (score 0):

> Cached binary found at /root/.npm/node-sass/4.14.1/linux-x64-83_binding.node
>   Binary found at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-83/binding.node
>   Testing binary

I would say the issue *could* be the fact it's using a cached version from before you upgraded to Ubuntu 20, in which case, removing the cached binary would resolve this.

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html

This is just my assumption, what have you tried so far to resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried to clear the cache, despite system warnings.  Did not help.

Comment: npm uninstall node-sass. After: npm install node-sass. Did not help.